# How to implement two way binding with Swift?

Tags: swift2, couchbase-lite

How to implement a two way data binding using Swift 2.0?

Let's assume I have the following model class (using couchbase lite):

```
@objc(Person)
class Person: NSObject{
    @NSManaged var firstName: NSString?
    @NSManaged var lastName: NSString?
}
```

And I like to bind the properties to a given formItemDescriptor like this:

```
class FormItemDescriptor {
    var tag: String?
    var value: Any?
}
```

How would I bind the `FormItemDescriptor.value` property to the `Person.firstName` property using 2-way-binding?

So changes in the model appear in the form and vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift does not support bindings out of the box, but you can achieve them with frameworks like [ReactiveKit](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit).

For example, when you declare an observable property you can bind it to another observable property.

```
let numberA: Property<Int>
let numberB: Property<Int>

numberA.bindTo(numberB)
```

To do bi-directional, just bind in other direction too:

```
numberB.bindTo(numberA)
```

Now, whenever you change any of them, the other will change.

Your example is bit harder though because you need to do bindings from @NSManaged properties that cannot be made `Observable`. It's not impossible, but to work the properties of Person should support key-value observing (KVO).

For example, given a Person object and a label, you could take an Property from KVO-enabled property with the method `rValueForKeyPath` and then bind that observable to the label, like this:

```
let person: Person
let nameLabel: UILabel

person.rValueForKeyPath("firstName").bindTo(nameLabel)
```

If you have an intermediately object like your `FormItemDescriptor`, then you'll have to make its properties observable.

```
class FormItemDescriptor {
  var tag: Property<String?>
  var value: Property<Any?>
}
```

Now you could establish binding

```
let person: Person
let descriptor: FormItemDescriptor

person.rValueForKeyPath("firstName").bindTo(descriptor.value)
```

Because `firstName` is not observable, you cannot do binding in another direction so you'll have to update it manually whenever `value` changes.

```
descriptor.value.observeNext { value in
  person.firstName = value as? NSString
}
```

We also had to do cast to `NSString` because `value` is of type `Any?`. You should rethink that though and see if you can make it a stronger type.

Note that UIKit bindings are coming from ReactiveUIKit framework. Check our documentation of [ReactiveKit](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I thought of doing both binding ways - `a.bindTo(b), b.bindTo(a)` - but was afraid of endless loops or any other weird behaviour. So it is truly save to do a two way binding of this kind by using ReactiveKit?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly safe - there is an internal mechanism that makes endless loops impossible.